# Get date without offset

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using MySQL to store my data. I'm recorded dates with different offset according to each timezone. What is important on those dates are only "effective" time. Here is an example:

```
date1 = "Thu, 27 Oct 2016 07:00:00 CEST +02:00"
# I want to get 700
date2 = "Thu, 27 Oct 2016 22:00:00 CEST +02:00"
# I want to get 2200
```

I would like to get these values to compare them with my current time. Then if it's currently "2016-11-17 10:12:00 +0100", I would like to compare on a `where` clause:

```
"1012" > "2200"
# or 
"1012" > "700"
```

Here is a fake record value:

```
# my_table
# | id | my_hour
# | XX | "Thu, 27 Oct 2016 07:00:00 CEST +02:00"
# | XY | "Thu, 27 Oct 2016 22:00:00 CEST +11:00"
```

Here is my code:

```
hour = Time.zone.now
# "2016-11-18 21:10:00 +0100"
where("CAST(DATE_FORMAT(my_hour,'%H%i') AS UNSIGNED) < ?", hour.strftime("%H%M").to_i)
# => Get XX record?
```

Comment: check this strategy. Far easier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32068755/267540

Comment: True story. Unfortunately I have to deal with timezone on this table. I don't have any other choice for now. That's why I'm asking this question but your answer is right in other circonstances. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strftime` to format date in Rails.

```
hour = Time.zone.now

MyTable.where("cast(strftime('%H%M', my_hour) as int) < ?", hour.strftime("%H%M").to_i)
```

here `MyTable` is your Model, `my_hour` is your date column and `hour` is current time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not working. `strftime` or `as int` seems to have some trouble to be executed. I tried with `DATE_FORMAT` instead of `strftime`  but still not working.